# OID need to match exactly for SNMP to work?

Tags: snmp, mib, oid, observium

I am trying to monitor a process on a Centos 7 server using SNMP, the monitoring system is Observium
my collegue added `proc java 10 1` to `snmpd.conf` and we know it's working on the server side because the snmpbulk command show

```
snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -On -c comunity localhost
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.2.1 = STRING: java
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.4.1 = INTEGER: 10
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.5.1 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.100.1 = INTEGER: noError(0)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.101.1 = STRING: 
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.102.1 = INTEGER: noError(0)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.103.1 = STRING:
```

we also know that observium support the mib UCD-SNMP-MIB, that contain the OID needed to monitor the process,
[OID of UCD-SNMP-MIB here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgYKj.png)
but the process do not show up in observium, and all the OID showed in the command `snmpbulkwalk` up there, at the end, have a .1 more that the OID wirte in the MIB

Do I need to add custom OID to observium that macht exactly the OID showed by the server, to make it work?

Comment: You might find an SNMP book to study further. A MIB document might define an object with OID "x.y.z", but depending on the object type (scalar or column), the actual instance has an OID of "x.y.z.0" or "x.y.z.{index}". In your case, the last ".1" is the index.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation